# Instagram Api, Subscription Update Data

Tags: spring-boot, instagram, instagram-api

A really short and simple question. I'm in the process of setting up a small spring boot app that will act as a gateway between Instagram and my personal website, the idea being I will write my own Angular directive that will display the data in the format I desire.

I fully understand the subscription set up and how it shall work. As I am unable to work on a instagram accessible environment until this evening I cannot test it as I wish to. The documentation is lacking in what format/structure the data will be received in (Data being the information sent by Instagram to my subscription endpoint)? My guess would be that it would replicate **GET/media/media-id** and return a **Media** object. Would anyone with experience of the Instagram api be able to confirm this for me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is facing the question I was:

I ended up running my client in a live environment. I simply grabbed the request object and printed it to a log file.

```
[{
    "object": "user",
    "object_id": "2124472252",
    "changed_aspect": "media",
    "time": 1497862007,
    "data": {
        "media_id": "<MEDIA_ID>"
    },
    "subscription_id": 0
}]
```